# Insert datetime.datetime object in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

I'm trying to insert my datettime object into MySQL

```
>>> t
datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 21, 19, 33, 36, tzinfo=tzutc())
>>> cursor.execute('INSERT INTO tweets(created_at) VALUES ({created_at})'.format(created_at=t))
```

Error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '19:33:36+00:00)' at line 1")
>>>
```

MySQL:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE mytable;
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

| created_at  | datetime            | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Try:>>> cursor.execute('INSERT INTO tweets (created_at) VALUES ("{created_at}")'.format(created_at=t)) Note the space and the "

Comment: I don't know anything about databases (yet), but the string formatting you're using will implicitly call `str` on your datetime object and use that string to substitute for `{created_at}`.  From the error, it looks like that string is what is causing mysql to choke.

Comment: Nice! Well I put it as an answer, I'll be glad if your aprove it!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to insert a space after your table name and to put your text inside "", like this:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO tweets (created_at) VALUES ("{created_at}")'.format(created_at=t))
```

Comment: Using the `format` string method should be avoided. Variables don't get escaped and you'll have SQL injection issues. See [Django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#connections-and-cursors) on the issue.

Comment: I do agree with you, but in his case this variable comes from internal code only. Is this subject to injection too? I'm not being ironic, I'm realy asking you, I'm not a literate in sanitized coding.

Comment: It's best to always keep things standardised and to do things the correct way every time. It will avoid confusion, and the possibility that the code may be used or copied without thinking into something that might introduce issues.

Answer (score 4):

Use parametrized sql instead of string formatting and manual quoting:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO tweets(created_at) VALUES (%s)', [t])
```

It's easier, and helps prevent [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).